# JSX not rendering whitespace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of individual characters, that I am using to map out a string.

However, the whitespace is being ignored. How can I implement this such that for each " " element in my array, it renders a white space?

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-field-wdiy6

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const elements = ["+", "-", " ", " ", "r"]
  return (
    <div>
      {elements}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Doing this, you will call the `toString()` function of an array. Try with `{elements.join(""}`

Comment: JSX renders HTML. Normal HTML whitespacing applies.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you treat these like strings, effectively the two consecutive spaces will be reduced into a single one here, because you're directly inside of a div.

You could try to use `"&nbsp"` instead of `" "` if you need to show real spaces somehow.

To display, you could join the characters into a string, you could do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const elements = ["+", "-", <>&nbsp;</> , <>&nbsp;</>, "r"];
    return (
      <div>
        {elements.map(c=>c)}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Note that I wrapped the   inside `<></>`, else it gets treated like a plain string, and will be rendered as such.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `pre tag`
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-dirac-rcviy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const elements = ["+", "-", " ", " ", "r"]
  return (
    <pre>
      {elements}
    </pre>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the pre tag or the css property white-space: pre-wrap;

```
export default function App() {
  const elements = ["+", "-", " ", " ", "r"];
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{elements.map(c => c)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```